# jshint boss true: what is it, why it exists?

Tags: javascript, jshint

I'm trying to convert a library to typescript and I have no idea what this javascript thing is called, it's history or purpose.

Why would anyone want to do this? `jshint boss: true` is a thing?

Reference: https://jshint.com/docs/options/#boss

> This option suppresses warnings about the use of assignments in cases
>   where comparisons are expected. More often than not, code like if (a =
>   10) {} is a typo. However, it can be useful in cases like this one:
>
> `js for (var i = 0, person; person = people[i]; i++) {}`
>
> You can silence this error on a per-use basis by surrounding the
>   assignment with parenthesis, such as:
>
> `js for (var i = 0, person; (person = people[i]); i++) {}`

Comment: `Why would anyone want to do this?` because it's valid code and they know what they are doing :p

Comment: It doesn’t have a specific name, it’s just an assignment expression. Some people think it’s hard to read. Sometimes it’s a mistake and `==` or `===` was intended. “boss” is just what JSHint (possibly from JSLint) decided to call the option and is definitely not a standard name or anything like that.

Comment: Related ESLint rules are [`no-cond-assign`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-cond-assign), [`no-return-assign`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-return-assign), and [`no-extra-parens`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-extra-parens).